# How to check memory leaks in simple Qt Widget application using Valgrind?

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I never use Valgrind before and today I tried to check memory leaks in simple Qt Widget application generated by Qt Creator. I created project by following steps:

1. I've got Qt Creator v4.8.1 based on Qt 5.12.0. In Qt Creator I chose following menu item: **File -> New File or Project... -> Application -> Qt Widgets Application**. Then I pressed **Choose... -> Next -> ... -> Finish**. Qt Creator generated following source code:

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**mainwindow.h**:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.ui**

```
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow" >
  <property name="geometry" >
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle" >
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar" />
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar" />
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget" />
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar" />
 </widget>
 <layoutDefault spacing="6" margin="11" />
 <pixmapfunction></pixmapfunction>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**untitled.pro**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2019-02-06T15:14:11
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

2. I compiled this project by GCC 8.2.0 toolchain in 'Debug mode' on Ubuntu 18.10.
3. Then i tried to run compiled program by following command:

   $ valgrind ./untitled

Result of this operations on Ubuntu 18.10 is:

```
==12228== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12228== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12228== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12228== Command: ./untitled
==12228== 
==12228== 
==12228== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==12228==  General Protection Fault
==12228==    at 0x15C006A7: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so)
==12228==    by 0x15C0DBC5: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so)
==12228==    by 0x15C0DFEB: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so)
==12228==    by 0x154B3172: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so)
==12228==    by 0x159AF457: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so)
==12228==    by 0x1587E5B1: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so)
==12228==    by 0x1587984D: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so)
==12228==    by 0x14F8BD3D: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0)
==12228==    by 0x14F63C52: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0)
==12228==    by 0x14F5F323: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0)
==12228==    by 0x14F5FD3C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0)
==12228==    by 0x14CFECF1: QXcbGlxWindow::createVisual() (in /opt/Software/Qt/5.12.0/gcc_64/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so)
==12228== 
==12228== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12228==     in use at exit: 3,561,397 bytes in 44,679 blocks
==12228==   total heap usage: 347,392 allocs, 302,713 frees, 29,095,722 bytes allocated
==12228== 
==12228== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12228==    definitely lost: 14,216 bytes in 80 blocks
==12228==    indirectly lost: 4,334 bytes in 203 blocks
==12228==      possibly lost: 28,587 bytes in 457 blocks
==12228==    still reachable: 3,448,988 bytes in 43,405 blocks
==12228==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==12228==                         length64           : 3,376 bytes in 61 blocks
==12228==                         newarray           : 2,048 bytes in 48 blocks
==12228==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12228== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==12228== 
==12228== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12228== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 4)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The program is crashing: `Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)`. Do you know why? If so, fix it first.

Comment: I use the default template of a QWidget application that Qt Creator creates. Without Valgrind it works normally and don't receive SIGSEGV.

Comment: Show the code you're using (update the post).

Comment: I've updated original post. Thank you for your advice and efforts to help me :)

Comment: I've built your code with the usual `qmake` followed by `make` and then run Valgrind and didn't get SIGSEGV. Try to clean the directory from the generated files and build again. Also, what exact commands are you using to build the program?

Comment: I made my experiments with Valgrind and Qt in my workplace, but today is a Saturday. I tried to repeat this experiment on my home notebook. I created project, then I run `qmake`, then `make`, and I received error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL`. Then I went to Web and searched how to install OpenGL. Then I ran this command: `sudo apt-get install cmake libx11-dev xorg-dev libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev libglew1.5 libglew1.5-dev libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev`. Then I ran `valgrind ./untitled` and all is OK! One on this libraries solves problem, but which one?

Comment: Seems like the GL lib didn't come with the installation of Ubuntu. If you go to https://packages.debian.org/sid/ and add the lib name after this address, you'll see the description of the lib.

Comment: On Monday I will try to install each library separately and will see which one is critical for Qt and Valgrind! After that I will post solution. Thank you, [user3132457](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3132457/user3132457).

Comment: Today I installed all libraries from list above, but error is on place. The only difference from my home notebook is that Ubuntu is installed on VM at work... And I have Ubuntu 18.04 at home, but 18.10 at work...

Comment: how did you build the program? your initial question was about getting a segfault, but now you're getting a linker error.

Comment: I had linker error on my home PC, but I've installed packages from list above and now the program works with Valgrind perfectly. But installation of this packages on my work PC don't solves problem with segfault. I build program by `qmake` then `make` on Ubuntu 18.10 VM and haven't got solution yet :(

Comment: the issue is in the environment. what are the versions of qt/compiler/valgrind/os you're using?

Comment: Qt 5.12.0/GCC 8.2.0/ Valgrind 3.13.0/Ubuntu 18.10. All packages except Qt is from standard Ubuntu's repository.

Comment: and what about the other environment? it's really hard to "debug" your issue without much information. maybe ask a colleague or someone who can help you in-house.